# Relationship between surface area and vapor pressure

Tags: vapor-pressure

How is vapor pressure independent of the surface area and volume of a liquid, although rate of evaporation depends on surface area?

Please someone help me I am totally confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rate of evaporation is proportional to surface area. The rate of condensation is proportional to surface area. The vapor pressure is the equilibrium pressure where the rate of evaporation is equal to the rate of condensation. Since the scaling factor is the same, the vapor pressure is independent of the surface area.

Comment: Sorry but why is rate of condensation proportional to surface area?

Comment: @samjoe Because it's the microscopic reverse of evaporation.